# Azure DevOps - Can't see many of the work items in backlog

Tags: azure-devops

I set up my first AzureDevops organisation by starting with the Agile process but later changed it to CMMI for the organisation to better align with the other projects my team works on. I think this is where the cause of the problem is but can't figure out how to address it.

PROBLEM:
I cannot see in the backlogs any of the Epics I created. The Epic selector in the dropdown menu of the backlog navigation is present and selected. Some of the Features can be seen in the Features backlog, however, not all.

WHAT I TRIED TO DO:
I created a query from the Epics backlog and tried changing its filters and got to see all the epics if I change the filter from having several OR statements on the Area Path filter to one with `Area Path Under "top level area path"`.

I am 100% sure this is because I changed the process. Would appreciate if someone could please let me know some troubleshooting steps to address the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having a possibly similar issue where I have my backlog with Epics, Features, and User Stories in a hierarchy. If I change the Area for one of my Epics from being the top-level Area, it disappears from the Backlog.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Had to go into Team configuration and explicitly give the team permission on the new Areas I created.